# Count number of records logged by week - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count

I know this is relatively simple but I can't find a solution within the archives although i see similar ones but my SQL isn't adequate enough to reverse engineer them.

All I am trying to do is count the number of calls raised within a team grouped by weeks from a call management table.  Here is an example of some code which returns a count of 30,000 plus entries.  I'd like to see that number divided down into weeks and also perhaps days based on a friday to friday range if possible?

```
select COUNT(*) from opencall 
where 
trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
```

The key fields are

```
logdate
```

Table name is

```
opencall
```

So I can then create a list of the number of calls logged by that suppgroup per week so

```
Week      Calls Logged
Week 1       134
Week 2       135
Week 3       189
...
...
```

So quite simple but I could then use this code to do searches on all sorts of different fields to identify some patterns.

All our date fields are VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

I can group this count by day simply enough using

```
    select COUNT(*), trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'))

    from opencall 
    where 
    trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
    group by  trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) 
    order by trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'))
```

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get count by week you must group by `trunc(your_date, 'IW')`, but if you want for friday to friday you must use `next_day` function and then group by `trunc(NEXT_DAY(your_date,'FRIDAY'), 'IW')` so, your query should be something like this:

```
select 
'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY'), 'IW')) WEEK,
count(*) Calls Logged
from opencall
where trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
group by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY'), 'IW')   
order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY'), 'IW');
```

Comment: Excellent and brilliant solution.  I can use this as a basis for so many calls now filtering on all sorts of fields.  Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `closedby` from the query:

```
with closed_calls as (
       select to_number(to_char(closedate, 'IW') as week_number, oc.*
       from opencall oc
       where  ((status > 15 or status = 6) and
              closedby in ('analyst1', 'analyst2', 'analyst3', 'analyst4', 'analyst5', 'analyst6', 'analyst7') and
              trunc(closeddate) between date '2014-10-01' and date '2014-12-31' 
      )
select week_number as "Week number", count(*) as "Calls closed"
from   closed_calls
group by week_number
order by week_number desc;
```

Note that I changed the date arithmetic.  Presumably `closedate` is stored as a date/time value in the database.  If so, you don't need to convert it to a string for comparisons.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your contribution.  This seems to complain about a missing right parenthesis.  I've tried adding one....   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 50

Comment: closedate is actually a VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)